# What modules to use for Perl Client to API which uses JSON-RPC protocol?

Tags: perl, json-rpc, mojolicious

I am looking to develop a perl client to an API which uses JSON-RPC.  What are the best modules to use for this?  Is using Mojolicious possible/ efficient?

Answer (score 2):

Mojolicious has very nice JSON encoding/decoding, while the following sample isn't exactly JSON-RPC, it's trivial to make it fully compliant:

```
post '/prefetch' => sub {
    my ($self) = @_;

    my $post = $self->req->json;

    my %row;
    for my $key (qw(country state city district suburb address number complement latitude longitude)) {
        $row{$key} = $post->{$key} if exists $post->{$key};
    }
```

Comment: is that test better written as `if defined $post->{$key}`?

Comment: Thanks @JoelBerger! Seems like a cargo cult from an old code :P